# Oracle extract alpha characters from string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to extract only alpha characters separately. 
For example Output for "**NIC132DA.1**"  should be "**NIC**" and "**DA**" separately without any numbers.

I tried following query:

```
select regexp_replace('NIC132DA.1','[^A-Za-z]') from dual;
```

I get following output: **NICDA**

 Expected out put is "NIC" and "DA" separately. 

Note: Number of alpha characters are not fixed in input string.

Comment: yes separate columns, in my query I tried only for one column

Comment: expected result is "NIC DA" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm):

```
select 
    regexp_substr('NIC132DA.1','[A-Za-z]+', 1, 1) first,
    regexp_substr('NIC132DA.1','[A-Za-z]+', 1, 2) second
from dual;
```

It's better to use multilingual character class [`[:alpha:]`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm):

```
select 
    regexp_substr('NIC132DA.1','[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 1) first,
    regexp_substr('NIC132DA.1','[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 2) second
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks very much it works and I tried with more alpha characters too.